# jQuery - how to find a specific JavaScript object inside an array within an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object in javaScript:

```
var stuffObject = {
     stuffArray1 : [object1, object2, object3],
     stuffArray2 : [object4, object5, object6]
}
```

object1 to 6 look like this:

```
object1 = {
   dataStuff : {
       stuffId: "foobar"
   }
}
```

My question: given the key "foobar", how do I retrieve object1 from the stuffObject using jQuery? The key "stuffId" always has a unique value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, using the input of other people I have solved it myself:

```
getStuffById: function(id){
    for (stuffArray in stuffObject) {
            for (stuff in stuffObject[stuffArray]) {
                if (stuffObject[stuffArray][stuff].dataStuff.stuffId == id) {
                    return stuffObject[stuffArray][stuff];
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

This also works better than the (now deleted) answer that uses .grep(), as this function terminates as soon as it finds the correct object.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around iterating over the set to find the object you are looking for. jQuery can't really help with that. Its purpose is DOM manipulation. If you want functionality to deal with objects, sets, lists, etc., check out [lodash](http://lodash.com/).

I wrote a function to deal with the problem. I hope it's understandable.

```
var stuffObject = {
    stuffArray1 : [{dataStuff: {stuffId: 'foobar'}}, {dataStuff: {stuffId: 'foo'}}, {}],
    stuffArray2 : [{}, {dataStuff: {stuffId: 'bar'}}, {}]
}

function getObjByStuffId(stuffObject, stuffId) {
    var key, arr, i, obj;
    // Iterate over all the arrays in the object
    for(key in stuffObject) {
        if(stuffObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr = stuffObject[key];
            // Iterate over all the values in the array
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                obj = arr[i];
                // And if it has the value we are looking for
                if(typeof obj.dataStuff === 'object'
                   && obj.dataStuff.stuffId === stuffId) {
                    // Stop searching and return the object.
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log('foobar?', getObjByStuffId(stuffObject, 'foobar') );
console.log('foo?', getObjByStuffId(stuffObject, 'foo') );
console.log('bar?', getObjByStuffId(stuffObject, 'bar') );
```